# Содержит ли абзац впечатление?

Tags: стилистика, общие-вопросы, лексика

Имеем следующий абзац:
"Согласно официального заявления разработчика(ов), переход на +1/-1 уровень боев для техники выше IV уровня осуществлен не будет, поскольку это "плохо скажется на разнообразии боев". И вот мне стало интересно, почему разброс +1/-1 для V-X - "плохо скажется на разнообразии боев", а для I-IV - нет? Ведь уровни I-ІV имеют меньший "ассортимент" техники, что уменьшает разнообразие боев. В такой ситуации более логичным было именно для III-IV оставить разброс +2/-2, а не для старших."

Содержит ли данный абзац впечатление?

Answer (score 1):

*Содержит ли данный абзац впечатление?*

Абзац содержит такие "впечатления":

1.Ошибка в падеже: нужно "согласно заявлени**ю**" (ср. согласно параграф**у** 1 заявлени**я**).

2.После утверждения "осуществлён не будет" логичнее сослагательное наклонение (напр. "сказалось бы"). Либо можно заменить "поскольку" на "иначе" (= если будет).

3.В конце неясно, к чему относится "старших" (нужно добавить "уровней", если это имеется в виду).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Впечатлен.
По пункту 2. Согласно контекста, слово "поскольку" можно было заменить разве что на "потому что". Потому что "сказалось бы" - предположение, а не утверждение, которое, в данном конкретном случае, имело место.